# How to get the current active menu item in Perl TK?

Tags: perl

I am creating a Context Menu in Perl Tk and would like to bind the Up and Down arrow pressed event to scroll through the menu items.

How can i get the current active menu item?

I know `$menu->activate(index)` will activate a menu item based on an `index` number but i don't know how to get the current activated index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Tk::Menu](http://p3rl.org/Tk::Menu), the following should work (not tested):

```
my $index = $menu->index('active');
```